# [Hive]How can I change the output file name from 000000_0.gz to PREFIX-000000_0.gz?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hql, oozie

As the title says, I want to add some prefix to output files generated by the following hql. Is that possible to designate a prefix?

`INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY outputDir SELECT ... FROM ...;`

Comment: Why? ...................

Comment: Just because I want not to modify the another job which uses the output.
If the file name has changed, I have to alter the source code as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have just answered this on another question[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46547031/naming-convention-of-part-files-in-hdfs/46548860#46548860)

I think you should be able to do

```
set mapreduce.output.basename = "part-";
```

Comment: i had a look at the underlying code and this won't work.