# naming convention of part files in HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

When we do an INSERT INTO command in Hive, the result of the execution creates multiple part files in HDFS.

e.g.  part-*-***** or 000000_0,000001_0 etc or something else.

Is there a configuration/setting that controls the naming of these part files?

The cluster I work in creates 000000_0, 000001_0, 000000_1 etc. I would like to change this to part- or text- etc so that its easier for me to pick these files up and merge them if needed.

If there is a setting that can be set in Hive right before executing the HQL, that would be ideal.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like this requires a custom file writer as @shainnif wrote in the comment below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should be able

```
set mapreduce.output.basename = part-;
```

This won't work. The only way I have found is with a custom file writer.

Comment: Tried it before and did not work. it still creates 00000_0 like files.

Comment: Which query engine are you using?

Comment: Hey prasanna, I had some time to test this above, it doesn't get picked up it can be done but requires a custom file writer